# explain this anchor tag syntax

Tags: html, ionic-framework, anchor

In the ionic ion-nav-view documentation there is an anchor tag syntax I've never seen before. I'm wondering if this syntax of combining a hashtag with a forward slash is unique to Ionic or what.

```
<script id="home" type="text/ng-template">
  <!-- The title of the ion-view will be shown on the navbar -->
  <ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
      <!-- The content of the page -->
      ****<a href="#/music">****Go to music page!</a>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything after a # in a url is called the "fragment identifier" and tells the browser where on the page to direct the user's attention.

In traditional web pages you're probably used to seeing fragment identifiers that are just a word, but just about anything (certainly including /) is a valid character in a fragment identifier.

So I wouldn't say it's different syntax - you still just have a url with a fragment identifier.

In an SPA world, where you want to be able to address a range of "virtual pages" without actually causing a new page load, putting what looks like a path in the fragment ID makes sense.  Typically scripts on the browser side react to the fragment ID to load appropriate resources via AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

It's a way to allow navigation in SPA that doesn't require a page refresh and also allows to use regular browser bookmarks.